# SolrJ with Apache Storm java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET

Tags: java, maven, solrj, apache-storm, build-dependencies

I want to integrate Storm topology with SolrJ, but I am getting this error

```
thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.setDefaultHttpParams(DefaultHttpClient.java:181)
```

It supposed to be dependency problem, but I checked my classpath and there is right versions of http-client and http-core and no duplicate.

For this issue is already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120471/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-def-content-charset) question, but there is no other information just he had solved it.

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>group.id</groupId>
<artifactId>twittertosolr</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Atilika Open Source repository</id>
        <url>http://www.atilika.org/nexus/content/repositories/atilika</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- STANFORD -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atilika.kuromoji</groupId>
        <artifactId>kuromoji</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.msd.gic.twitter.storm.Topology</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.msd.gic.twitter.storm.Topology</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned post has a comment regarding versions. I can see that you are using solrj 5. Its the latest one. There are lot of changes in the way you index the data in Solr 5. Please paste the code snippet you are using.

Comment: I have tried it in many ways,  finally what helps was just to make different new project again with the same pom.xml and download the dependencies again. I don't know why, but now it works properly and I can say this is the right configuration. It was some magic problem  - maybe some cache, maven repository, eclipse IDE problem,...definitely something with classpath.